# a.s. convergence and a subsequent argument

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

This is a question about a.s. convergence and a subsequent argument.

Let $\{X_t\}_{t>0}$ be a real-valued stochastic process defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. We assume  that $\lim_{t \downarrow 0}X_t =0$ in probability.

Let  $\{t_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $t_n \downarrow 0$ as $n \to \infty$, and $\{t_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a subsequence of  $\{t_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Because $\lim_{t \downarrow 0}X_t =0$ in probability, we have a subsequence $\{t_{n_{k_l}}\}_{l=1}^{\infty}$ of $\{t_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\lim_{l \to \infty}X_{t_{n_l}}=0$ $P$-a.s.

However,  this would not imply that $\lim_{n \to \infty }X_{t_n}=0$ $P$-a.s. because a.s. convergence is not metrizable in general. Then, we assume moreover that the map $t \mapsto X_t$ is continuous $P$-a.s.

**In this case, can we show that $\lim_{n \to \infty }X_{t_n}=0$ $P$-a.s. ?**

I think this is a correct claim. Do you know the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true.  Let $(Y_n)$ be a sequence which converges in probability but not almost surely. Let $X_t =Y_n$ when $t=\frac  1 n$  and let $X_t$ have a linear graph in $[\frac 1 {n+1},\frac 1 n]$ for each $n$.  Since $|X_t| \leq \max \{|X_{\frac 1 {n+1}}|,|X_{\frac 1 n}|\}$ we see that $X_t \to 0$ in probability. Take $t_n=\frac 1  n$. Then $X_{t_n}\equiv Y_n$ is not almost surely convregent.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I understood your counter example.